# OnMeasure get wrong value when in XML width and height are all fixed

Tags: android, xml, onmeasure

I was developing a customized view when I encountered this problem. In the XML I set the `layout_width` & `layout_height` with fixed value `100dp`. But in `onMeaure()` method I got `widthMeasureSpec` with measureMode `EXACTLY`, but `heightMeasureSpec` with measureMode  `AT_MOST`. What's more weird is that they come with different size value. Here's the XML and related code fragment:

CODE:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int widthMeasureMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthMeasureSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMeasureMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightMeasureSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

[image: Actual Value in Debug Mode]

XML:

```
<com.my.view
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/theme"
    app:contentSizeRatio="50%"
    app:imageSource="@drawable/ic_logo_white_48"/>
```